# Can any divergent real sequence ${c_n}≤O(n)$ be written as the Cauchy product of two convergent sequences?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Show or give a counterexample that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent.

Let $\{c_n\}$ be a real divergent sequence.

$(1)$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}{n}=M\ (M\in\mathbb{R})$.

$(2)$ There exist
two real convergent sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ such that $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$.

I have known how to show $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, but for $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ can we give a constructive proof? Of course there possibly exists a counterexample.